# Need to add blinker module to relay trigger

Tags: led, relay, 12v

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWJmI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a simple light controller box. I have a 2 channel relay that controls a red and green light by magnetic switch. so we can tell from a distance if the door is open or closed. i have the switch part working great, but people are not gentle in my warehouse so the magnetic switches have been broken a few times. now i have a dpst switch installed on each unit and it was originally set to ground out both led's so they would make yellow. this is not working for us. I am now trying to add a basic motorcycle blinker to my design so we can make the relay constantly alternate red and green until the magnet gets fixed. the blinker wont blink. is there an inexpensive and safe way to make the blinker alternate the voltage on the switch of the relay so i can get this better. The supplier said to add a 5w load to it. Can i just add a 1ohm 5w resistor to the mix? When the magnet is down it could be two days of run time before I can get in and fix the issue. Any help would be much appriciated. I have also added a diagram of how I wired the unit. Feel free to let me know of changes that are needed. FYI I can not change the relay to run + instead of - because we also have strip rgb leds on the other side of the door that have constant positive and ground out each color needed.  Thank you for your time.!

Answer (score 1):

If the blinker module was intended to be used on a motorcycle, it probably uses the lamp current to heat a bimetalic strip that opens the circuit when hot.  The LEDs won't pass enough current to produce the heat needed to make the blinker operate.

You could add one or two incandescent turn signal lamps to the circuit, on the output side of the blinker module, to give it enough current.